# Minimal covering circle

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

There are $n<10^4$ points on the plane. How can one approximately (with a given precision $2^{-20}$ of points' coordinates) find the minimal radius of a circle that covers some $k$ out of $n$ these points?

There is [lots of information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem) on the case $k=n$ in Wikipedia, but I found nothing on general case.

Comment: As seen on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386251/minimal-covering-circle/26389077#26389077